# Two .NET assemblies appear to conflict with each other

Tags: c#, uwp

I get the following error in my build attempts as soon as I reference the two .NET assemblies below. I've tried downgrading System.Security.Access control from 5.0.0.0 to 4.0 (next lowest version in NuGet) but no change in build.

My .csproj only references System.Security.Access 5.0.0.0 as far as I can see, so I don't think I can change anything there.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1705  Assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl' with identity 'System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' uses 'System.Security.AccessControl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Security.AccessControl' with identity 'System.Security.AccessControl, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    FolderAssess
```

The output log seems to be pointing toward UWP itself being where the problem is coming from

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FolderAssess, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Security.Principal.Windows" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "System.Security.Principal.Windows, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Security.Principal.Windows, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
:     "System.Security.Principal.Windows, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Security.Principal.Windows, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
:     References which depend on "System.Security.Principal.Windows, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll].
:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll
:           Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll".
:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll
:     References which depend on "System.Security.Principal.Windows, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll].
:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.AccessControl.dll
:           Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.AccessControl.dll".
:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.AccessControl.dll
:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\mscorlib.dll
:           Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\mscorlib.dll".
:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\mscorlib.dll
:             Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup
:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.AccessControl.dll
:             C:\Users\Me\.nuget\packages\system.io.filesystem.accesscontrol\5.0.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll
:         C:\Users\Me\.nuget\packages\system.io.filesystem.accesscontrol\5.0.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll
:           Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\Me\.nuget\packages\system.io.filesystem.accesscontrol\5.0.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll".
:             C:\Users\Me\.nuget\packages\system.io.filesystem.accesscontrol\5.0.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll
:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\mscorlib.dll
:             Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup
:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.AccessControl.dll
: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Security.AccessControl" that could not be resolved.
: There was a conflict between "System.Security.AccessControl, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Security.AccessControl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
:     "System.Security.AccessControl, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Security.AccessControl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
:     References which depend on "System.Security.AccessControl, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.AccessControl.dll].
:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.AccessControl.dll
:           Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.AccessControl.dll".
:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.AccessControl.dll
:     References which depend on "System.Security.AccessControl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\System.Security.AccessControl.dll].
:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\mscorlib.dll
:           Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\mscorlib.dll".
:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\mscorlib.dll
:             Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup
:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.AccessControl.dll
:             C:\Users\Me\.nuget\packages\system.io.filesystem.accesscontrol\5.0.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll
         C:\Users\Me\.nuget\packages\system.io.filesystem.accesscontrol\5.0.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll
           Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\Me\.nuget\packages\system.io.filesystem.accesscontrol\5.0.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll".
             C:\Users\Me\.nuget\packages\system.io.filesystem.accesscontrol\5.0.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\mscorlib.dll
             Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup
             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.12\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.AccessControl.dll
CSC : error CS1705: Assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl' with identity 'System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' uses 'System.Security.AccessControl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Security.AccessControl' with identity 'System.Security.AccessControl, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\XamlCompiler\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(482,5): error MSB4181: The "CompileXaml" task returned false but did not log an error.
```

All of these assemblies work for me in the interactive window, I only get errors on build
Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: In .NET world, you can usually fix that with a `bindingRedirect` entry in the config file. Not sure about UWP-land

Comment: Looks like someone reported a similar problem on github. I'll try manually creating an app.config with a redirect as suggested. 
There's also a comment about appdomain.assemblyresolve  working instead of binding redirection, but first things first.
[link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/5471)

Comment: Are your .NET assemblies .NET Standard 2.0 assembilities?

Comment: @Roy Li - I'm not sure. UWP only asks me what Windows 10 SDK I want to target. I'm targeting 1903 if that helps.

Also, I was unable to get bindingredirect to work. To be fair, I could have done it wrong. According to MS docs, UWP doesn't use app.config. That said, there are a few bugfixs on github that mention using bindingredirect to fix a bug in EntityFramework back in 2016. Maybe the ability to manually create & add  app.config to UWP was removed?

Comment: Are these  .NET assemblies that you want to refer to created by yourself?

Comment: No, they are all first party asesmblies. It looks like UWP is the problem. I rewrote the class in a WPF project and everything seems to work just fine.

Comment: This is still a problem. I can't seem to find any resolution to force UWP to use an older version rather that the current version that is in conflict with Microsoft Graph shipping version.

Comment: Unlike @Cypher, we are developing for Microsoft HoloLens 2 which requires UWP, we have no choice.